# Run whole test folder acts differently

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have classes like this.

```
class A(){
   String returnSth(){return "a";}
}

class B extends A{
    @Override
     String returnSth(){return "b";}
  }

public class ProductionConfig{

   @Bean
   @Profile("!test")
   public A a{
      return A();
   } 
}

public class TestConfig{

   @Bean
   @Profile("test")
   public B b{
      return B();
   }
}
```

And test class like this, when I ran only that method, it passes but when I ran test folder (which contains anohter unrelated test classes), it fails. I put a breakpoint on `B.returnSth()` and it's not also stopping by for that method when I ran whole folder. Any idea why this is happening ?

```
public class ATest extends TestConfig {
   @Autowired
   private B b;

   @Test
   public void test(){
      Assert.assertTrue(b.returnSth(), "b");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was related to `@Profile` annotation, it was creating real beans instead of mock ones and due to that test cases behaved strangely.

A clear explanation that you can find here ;

https://reflectoring.io/dont-use-spring-profile-annotation/

> Profiles should be used for exactly one reason: to create a
> configuration profile for a runtime environment.

Instead of `@Profile` annotation `@ConditionalOnProperty` can be used.